# How many discharge cycles do ISS and other LEO satellites withstand? What specific things are done to make this possible?

Tags: solar-power, battery

Batteries in our laptops and phones eventually wear out after thousands or tens of thousands of discharge cycles over the lifetime of the product, maybe a cycle ever few days.

The ISS and other satellites in LEO very often are eclipsed perhaps fifteen times a day.

What management strategies are used to maintain their battery life? For example, do they discharge a different subsection of the battery for each eclipse rather than cycle the whole thing between say 90% and 100% every 90 minutes? Do they use types of cells that are very different than those used in consumer electronics?

- [How deleterious is topping-off my Li-ion batteries (phone/laptop) every time they drop to 90%?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/231469/102305)

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer - addressing the questions about managing the system for the ISS

tl;dr it's done manually by the ground

> If the Primary Power System batteries are not discharged, they can
> overcharge, thereby causing damage to the batteries. Or, they can
> develop a memory, meaning the full depth of discharge (i.e., time that
> a rechargeable battery can last on a single discharge) would not be
> available. Ground controllers must actively manage battery states of
> charge during high beta operations by reducing the current used to
> charge batteries and occasionally deactivating batteries to prevent
> them from overcharging. As a result, some of the power that is
> generated is wasted and cannot be used by the EPS. Annually, batteries
> must be reconditioned by taking each battery off-line and completely
> discharging it to remove any memory buildup and allowing the state of
> charge (SOC) software calculations to be updated
>
> ...
>
> From a planning perspective, the operations team plans for the
> batteries to fully recharge each orbit and is limited to a maximum
> discharge down to 65% SOC to prevent excessive wear on the battery
> hardware and maintain contingency reserve power in case of a failure
> preventing a battery from recharging.
>
> ...
>
> All these operations are carefully defined in the flight rules, which detail under what conditions the batteries can be discharged below the nominal limits.

From [The International Space Station Operating an Outpost in the New Frontier](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/iss-operating_an_outpost-tagged.pdf) page 161

Note: NASA does not make the ISS Flight Rules publicly available.